# OpenShift: how do I assign a password to user?

Tags: openshift

I can do this in OpenShift 4.2:

```
$ oc create user jeff
```

Then doing this causes error:

```
$ oc login -u jeff
Authentication required for https://some.server:6443 (openshift)
Username: jeff
Password:
```

What is the password? I was never given a chance to type that in.

I don't know if an Identify Provider is configured or not. We must be using the default to my knowledge.

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you using and what identity provider is configured?

Comment: @Klis Thanks for your reponse. I'm using 4.2 and I don't really know if an identity provider besides default is configured. I don't know how to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at the OpenShift documentation and there is only kubeadmin mentioned as user. Also, no identity provider is configured in the ignition files.
My suggestion to you is to set up "some" identity provider, [possibly htpasswd identity provider.](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/authentication/identity_providers/configuring-htpasswd-identity-provider.html)

After that, you can add users to htpasswd file and don't forget to add permissions.

EDIT: Here is the [link](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/authentication/identity_providers/configuring-htpasswd-identity-provider.html#identity-provider-configuring-using-the-web-console_configuring-htpasswd-identity-provider) where you can check what identity provider is currently configured.